# read() function for FileReader reads 8212

Tags: encoding, binaryfiles, filereader

I'm trying to read the binary content of a text file (which contains the compressed version of a different text file).  The first two characters (01111011 and 00100110) are correct (going by the values that were original put there during the compression process.

However, when it gets to the third character, it should be reading 10010111 (again, going by what was added during the compression process), but instead it reads 10000000010100 (aka 8212).  Does anyone know what is causing this discrepancy, or how to fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: Without any code, compression details or even details on what platform/programming language you're talking about, it's very hard to give any intelligent input.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I'm using Java, and my IDE is Eclipse.  The compression method isn't really relevant - all that matters is that I be able to read back the same binary data that I put into the text file earlier - something that works when reading the first two bytes, but screws up on the third byte for unknown reasons.

I think the problem relates to me not understanding how the read() method of FileReader works under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) should not be used to read binary data from files since it reads a *character* at a time using the default encoding (which is most likely not very good for binary reading)

Instead, use [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) which has read methods that reads actual raw bytes without any encoding applied.